# Why can Selenium click on radio button using Chrome & Firefox but fails with IE 9?

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using Python 3.4 with [Selenium Webdriver python bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). I'm running on a windows machine.
The following script works to test my website when I use the Selenium Chrome and Firefox webdrivers. However, when I switch to the IE webdriver, it fails. Here is my script:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie()               # Line #1
appURL = ("http://localhost:3000")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(appURL)


print("Waiting for 'MyRadio' to be present")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'MyRadioButtonID')))
print("'MyRadio' is present")


myRadioBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("MyRadioButtonID")
print("myRadioBtn = %s" % myRadioBtn)
print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("disabled") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("disabled"))
print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("class") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("class"))
print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("data-name") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("data-name"))
print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("data-key") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("data-key"))
print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("name") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("name"))
print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("type") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("type"))
print('myRadioBtn.is_enabled() = %s' % myRadioBtn.is_enabled())
print('myRadioBtn.is_displayed() = %s' % myRadioBtn.is_displayed())
print('dir(myRadioBtn) = %s' % dir(myRadioBtn))
print("\n")


print("About to click 'MyRadio'")
time.sleep(3)
myRadioBtn.click()               # Line #28


print('myRadioBtn.get_attribute("value") = %s' % myRadioBtn.get_attribute("value"))
print("Clicked 'MyRadio' 1")
```

As I stated above, this works fine for Chrome and Firefox. However, when I change line #1 to "Ie", it fails in line #28. I have IE 9 installed. The error message is `"ElementNotVisibleException: Message: 'Cannot click on element'"` this happens 100% of the time. Below is the output generated by that failure.

```
Waiting for 'MyRadio' to be present
'MyRadio' is present
myRadioBtn = <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0299F290>
myRadioBtn.get_attribute("disabled") = None
myRadioBtn.get_attribute("class") = myClass
myRadioBtn.get_attribute("data-name") = myDataName
myRadioBtn.get_attribute("data-key") = myKey
myRadioBtn.get_attribute("name") = myName
myRadioBtn.get_attribute("type") = radio
myRadioBtn.is_enabled() = True
myRadioBtn.is_displayed() = False

dir(myRadioBtn) = ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_execute', '_id', '_parent', '_upload', 'clear', 'click', 'find_element', 'find_element_by_class_name', 'find_element_by_css_selector', 'find_element_by_id', 'find_element_by_link_text', 'find_element_by_name', 'find_element_by_partial_link_text', 'find_element_by_tag_name', 'find_element_by_xpath', 'find_elements', 'find_elements_by_class_name', 'find_elements_by_css_selector', 'find_elements_by_id', 'find_elements_by_link_text', 'find_elements_by_name', 'find_elements_by_partial_link_text', 'find_elements_by_tag_name', 'find_elements_by_xpath', 'get_attribute', 'id', 'is_displayed', 'is_enabled', 'is_selected', 'location', 'location_once_scrolled_into_view', 'parent', 'rect', 'send_keys', 'size', 'submit', 'tag_name', 'text', 'value_of_css_property']


About to click 'MyRadio'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myFile.py", line 28, in <module>
    myRadioBtn.click()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",line 65, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",line 385, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: 'Cannot click on element'
```

Why is it that the this radio button can be clicked on using the Firefox and Chrome drivers, but not IE? I can clearly see the radio button is visible. And manually, I can click it. So why can't selenium?

Comment: This happens from time to time. From the top of my head, there are two possible solutions, 1: downgrade your IE version or 2: use selenium to perform a more "crude" click on coordinates instead of clicking on a button.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change my IE version. I need to do the experiment on this particular version of IE.

Comment: Can u try to click on the element using JavascriptExecutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try changing the expected condition to [`visibility_of_element_located`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located):

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
>   page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only
>   displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

Note that you don't need to find the button again, it returns the web element:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MyRadioButtonID')))
element.click()
```

---

Also, for IE, setting a higher [implicit wait timeout](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#implicit-waits) may have a positive impact:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

The Selenium Internet Explorer web driver is not native to the browser and often has problems locating elements on the screen. I suspect this is the problem you are having.

Comment: [There is hope](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/06/16/announcing-internet-explorer-developer-channel.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

You should try by disabling browser native event. Thanks Jim Evans for explaining [Native event](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html) so broadly

```
profile = driver = webdriver.Ie() 
profile.native_events_enabled = False
driver = webdriver.Ie(profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Locators values you using must changing in IE, because it happens IE behaves differently than FF and Chrome, try using locators which are specify to IE or which are visible using IE